# Password Keeps "resetting"

Tags: login, password, password-recovery

I'm not very proficient with Linux, so please excuse my ignorance.  We have an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation, and we use it to run FOG.  We are running FOG on it in an virtual environment, and we don't use it for any other reason.

Here over the last few months my account on Ubuntu has had the password changing for some reason.  I can't log into the server at all.  Every time this happens I have to reboot, get into recover and do the mount -o rw,remount / command and change the password afterwards.

It will work for a bit, then it does it again.  Today, I reset it, logged in and updated FOG with no issues.  Right after that I was going to check for updates to Ubuntu, but I couldn't install them because my password was no longer valid.  I had to reset the password again, to log in and install updates.

I have been searching Google, and there are countless ways to reset/recover your password, but I can't find anyone that has a root cause of this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the  hypothesis to be hacked? Copy your `/etc/shadow` file in a secure place (external pen drive) and when it happens again compare them to see if it is changed something... or do the `md5sum` of the line of your user and sign somewhere...

Comment: We had a hardware failure, so we loaded up a new server and migrated all of our files from the old server.  I have had this problem off and on since that brand new installation.  I don't believe it is anything malicious.

Comment: Might be helpful to post this comment as an answer then accept it, John.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "post this comment as an answer then accept it."  Just accept that it is an issue, and move on with the way we have been doing things?

Comment: You stated _"had the password changing for some reason"_. It cannot be, not normally. Did you have a mechanism that expire the password and after sometime disallow the user to login? Are you sure that the password is changed? I ask because you can have the same effect (no possibility to login) without changing the password... but you have to search elsewhere... did you update Ubuntu regularly (security update)? Did you use a different password for the games and the user on Ubuntu ? Please [edit] your post adding this info.